# Intellij Idea GUI designer: move and set appropriate component position by mouse

Tags: java, forms

I've just migrated from Netbeans to Idea and got some problems with gui form designer. Is it possible to move and set appropriate component position by mouse? I've tried, but failed to set custom position on the form. As I understand, Idea form design is based on layouts, so position of components changes only from source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to work with layouts. There's no such thing as 'Design layout' in IntelliJ Idea. However, it helps to design nicer GUIs :)